# Qt designer - how to create QDialog?

Tags: qt-creator, qdialog

It is possibility to create QDialog in Qt-creator like for example QForm (by clicking)? I've found several samples, but QDialog is created programmatically.
I want to drag and drop buttons, listview and others components on QDialog.
Now I can add new components only by modifying code.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Select `File/New ...`; then from `Files and Classes`, pick `Qt`, and select `Qt Designer Form Class` from the right-hand-side panel.  `Choose ...` then takes you to another page where you can select a `Dialog`.

Comment: Ha! I just noticed that the question title says "Qt designer" (in which case my answer is correct), but the question body says "Qt-creator" (in which case your answer is correct). Let's vote each other up :-)

Answer (score 2):

The menu item `File|New...` gives you a choice of various dialog box types, in the `templates\forms` tab. (Qt version 4.7.0.)